# How to make PJSIP run in Android as a background service?

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

I am trying to build a voip capable Android application using PJSIP. I have compiled the latest PJSIP version from svn.

I tried many ways, but at the end i always find my self "not registered" (out of the location table) in the SIP Server (Kamailio in my case).

Can you please advise what is the best approach to keep PJSIP running good in the background as a service?

I am using TCP for signalling.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hay, have you got any solution ? I want to run PJSIP as background.

Comment: not really, still no luck

Comment: You can download csipsimple app (it uses pjsip library too) from Google Play Store and try to connect to your Kamailio sip server first.

FYI: pjsip 2.4.5 android works fine to me. (I use Kamailio too)

Comment: csipsimple is a huge project, i tried looking at the source code but not much luck. My issue at the end was keeping the user registered 24/7. I have managed to register and make calls and media was good. But i always lose registry after a while

Comment: @TareKhoury Did you found any solution?

Comment: @poqueque nope, gave up on this